# Use nativeDroid theme in Appery

Tags: jquery-mobile, themes, nativedroid

I'm trying to use nativeDroid as theme for an app built with Appery, but it doesn't work and I have no idea why. Can anybody explain the correct procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a problem with jquery-mobile version. Be surre you run version lower to 1.4. Otherwise it will show everything messed up

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery mobile version 1.4 try this native droid version  [nativeDroid v0.2.4](http://nativedroid.godesign.ch/?v=0.2.4)

#Note  : It is an experimental version